# UICollectionViewCell detect tap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have `UICollectionView` in `ViewController` class and I also have a class for `UICollectionViewCell`.

I have some cells and I need to detect which cell was tapped. How can I detect that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this delegate method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
         didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let tappedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:indexPath) as! CustomCellClass
    print(tappedCell.tag)
}
```

//

```
collectionView.delegate = self
```

//

```
class CustomVC:UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource { --- }
```

Comment: How can I detect tag of the selected cell?

Comment: @user6023982 Why do you need a tag? You are given the indexPath in this delegate method. You don't need a tag, you don't even need to access the cell for the indexPath.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for suggesting. I'll also try this method.

Comment: @user6023982 I didn't suggest anything. I asked you a few questions.

Comment: I need to find out which cell was pressed. Anyway your question helped me to understand correct way.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5 you can use the didSelectItemAt method:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath) //will return [0, 0] for the first cell, [0, 1] for the second cell etc...
}
```